# How do I check for convertibility in a tactic producing terms?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

Suppose I have the following tactic to check if a term is the literal zero:

```
Ltac isZero x :=
  match x with
  | O => constr:true
  | _ => constr:false
  end.

Goal Set.
  let isz := isZero O in pose isz.
  (* adds true to the context *)
```

Now imagine that I want the tactic to accept a bit more; maybe any term that is convertible with zero. If this was a tactic acting on the goal, I would do

```
Ltac isZero x :=
  match x with
  | ?v => unify v 0; constr:true
  | _  => constr:false
  end.
```

but this fails for a tactic producing terms:

```
Error: Value is a term. Expected a tactic.
```

How can I check for convertibility in a tactic producing terms? In this specific example reducing `x` or computing it (`let xx := eval compute in x`) may work, but in more complex example the cost of computing could be prohibitive, especially as I would need to reduce the two terms of the comparison.

PS: For reference, the unsimplified issue is that I'm trying to efficiently lookup a key probably matching a value in an `FMap` built by sequences of calls to `add`, and the tactic looks like

```
Ltac find_key value :=
  match fmap with
  | add ?k value _ => constr:(Some k)
  | add _ _ ?m => find_key value m
  | _ => constr:None
  end
```

With this implementation, if instead of `value` the map contains a term convertible to `value` but not syntactically equal to it, the tactic will incorrectly return `None`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to construct a term that triggers the conversion check; for instance:

```
Goal 2 + 2 = 4.

match goal with
| |- ?a = ?b =>
  let e := constr:(eq_refl a : a = b) in
  idtac "equal"
| |- _ => idtac "not equal"
end.
```

Normally, this prints "equal". However, if you replace `4` by, say, `3` in the goal above, the inner branch fails, printing "not equal".

Comment: Can't you use the `unify` tactic? https://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual010.html#hevea_tactic155

Comment: @Ptival, my question showed an example using unify, which doesn't work :) (in Arthur's example it would, though; but it has side effects, too)